# Join SQL Query Problem?

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-server

First Select Statement:

```
SELECT
dbo.FG_FILLIN.PartNumber,
dbo.DropshipPackinglist.Shiplist_Qty,
dbo.DropshipPackinglist.Quantity
FROM   dbo.FG_FILLIN INNER JOIN
       dbo.DropshipPackinglist ON 
       dbo.FG_FILLIN.PartNumber = dbo.DropshipPackinglist.PartNumber
WHERE  (dbo.FG_FILLIN.Batch = 'CIP_HK_6')
GROUP BY 
dbo.FG_FILLIN.Batch,
dbo.FG_FILLIN.PartNumber,
dbo.FG_FILLIN.ItemNumber,
dbo.DropshipPackinglist.Shiplist_Qty,
dbo.DropshipPackinglist.Quantity
```

Result :

```
PartNumber  Shiplist_Qty    Quantity
P02-070161-00111-C100   6   3
P02-070161-10111-C100   6   3
```

---

2nd :

```
SELECT PartNumber,COUNT(Batch) AS Created
FROM         dbo.FG_FILLIN
WHERE Batch='CIP_HK_6'
GROUP BY Batch,PartNumber
```

Result :

```
PartNumber  Created
P02-070161-00111-C100   3
P02-070161-10111-C100   1
```

Joining this two Query I cant show this one: RESULT NEEDED

```
PartNumber  Shiplist_Qty    Quantity  Created
P02-070161-00111-C100   6   3            3
P02-070161-10111-C100   6   3            1
```

It always show : when i Add `Count(dbo.FG_FILLIN.Batch) as Created`

```
PartNumber  Shiplist_Qty    Quantity  Created
P02-070161-00111-C100   6   3            6
P02-070161-10111-C100   6   3            2
```

Any Advice.? Thanks In Regards!

Comment: "Any advice?" What's the question again?

Comment: It's hidden somewhere "RESULT NEEDED"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Using a subselect:

```
   SELECT f.PartNumber,
          dpl.Shiplist_Qty,
          dpl.Quantity,
          (SELECT COUNT(Batch) AS Created
             FROM dbo.FG_FILLIN x
            WHERE x.batch = f.batch
              AND x.partnumber = f.partnumber
         GROUP BY Batch, PartNumber) AS created
     FROM dbo.FG_FILLIN f
    JOIN dbo.DropshipPackinglist dpl ON dpl.partnumber = f.partnumber
   WHERE f.Batch = 'CIP_HK_6'
GROUP BY f.Batch, f.PartNumber, f.ItemNumber, dpl.Shiplist_Qty, dpl.Quantity
```

### Using a JOIN to a derived table/inline view

```
   SELECT f.PartNumber,
          dpl.Shiplist_Qty,
          dpl.Quantity,
          x.created
     FROM dbo.FG_FILLIN f
     JOIN dbo.DropshipPackinglist dpl ON dpl.partnumber = f.partnumber
LEFT JOIN (SELECT t.partnumber,
                  t.batch,
                  COUNT(Batch) AS Created
             FROM dbo.FG_FILLIN t
         GROUP BY Batch, PartNumber) x ON x.partnumber = f.partnumber
                                      AND x.batch = f.batch
    WHERE f.Batch = 'CIP_HK_6'
 GROUP BY f.Batch, f.PartNumber, f.ItemNumber, dpl.Shiplist_Qty, dpl.Quantity
```

Change "LEFT JOIN" to "JOIN" if you only want to see parts that have `created` values.

Comment: Joining this two Query I cant show this one: RESULT NEEDED

    PartNumber Shiplist_Qty Quantity  Created
    P02-070161-00111-C100 6 3            6
    P02-070161-00111-C100 6 3            6

Comment: @Crimsonland: That's a duplicate, far as I can tell.  And it appears to have a `created` value...

Comment: Thanks Sir..I got the answer i added PO_NUmber on where clause..And it works.. Thanks Again..